# Can we have the fanciful red colors for moderator-only tags?

Tags: feature-request, design, android-app, moderator-tags

This surely is not a priority now but I really miss the fanciful red color for the 'status-' tags and other mod-only tags.

Can we have the color on the android app?

Comment: On a related note, tag markdown in posts doesn't work at all in the app. It just shows a link, not the pretty gray *or* red tags.